# base16-vim and base16-shell - Light themes not working

Tags: colorscheme

I'm trying to use base16-vim for a light color scheme. I want to use "one-light", but it seems that none of the light schemes work. After starting Vim with a light scheme, `:colo` reports default scheme. When I do the same after switching to a dark scheme, the correct one is reported.

I debugged the startup with `vim -D` and can see, that the correct light scheme is set in the beginning, but at the very end (I think it is caused by autocommands) it switches back to default.
I also checked log files of both startups (light/dark schemes) with vim `-V20debug.log` and found that the main difference (besides the colors of course) is, the the light scheme is loaded again at the end.

I already debugged Vim a lot, but do not know how to proceed. When I debug vim with `vim -D` for two different colorschemes (light/dark) I get this output (`:colo` is added by me to check current colorscheme):

light scheme:

```
Befehl: call s:LocalBrowse(expand("<amatch>"))
>colo
base16-one-light
Befehl: call s:VimEnter(expand("<amatch>"))
>colo
default
```

dark scheme:

```
Befehl: call s:LocalBrowse(expand("<amatch>"))
>colo
base16-onedark
Befehl: call s:VimEnter(expand("<amatch>"))
>colo
base16-onedark
```

Comment: Welcome to Vi&Vim SE. I recall a number of questions asked in the past related to base16 color schemes. Have you searched this site for those already? "base16" alone as a search term will probably be sufficient.

Comment: Perhaps [How to debug my vimrc](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/10604)?

Comment: Yes, I reviewed the base16 topics, but I think my issue is not discussed up to now.

Comment: Okay. One other question...don't take offense if this seems obvious to you as I helped someone with a base16 scheme problem with this very same recommendation: Are there installation instructions on whatever the scheme's home page is and, if so, did you follow them? (Many schemes just can be thrown in `colors` dir but some need special handling.)

Answer (score 1):

I have to set

```
set bg=dark
```

I found this [here](https://github.com/chriskempson/base16-vim/issues/78)

The recommendation for

```
colorscheme base16-default-dark
```

is probably wrong or not working in my setup.

Maybe there's a difference if you have you config in `~/.vimrc` compared to `.vim/vimrc`? I have mine in the second folder.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with getting the `gruvbox` colourscheme loaded on a remote installation.

This is definitely a hack, but I solved it by adding:

```
execute "colorscheme gruvbox"
```

to my .`vimrc`, which solved the issue.

Comment: That... doesn’t make any sense? I’m surprised it worked for whatever your situation was; there shouldn’t be any difference between `:execute "colorscheme gruvbox"` and `:colorscheme gruvbox`

Comment: I know right, my guess is that the execute command runs later or at a different priority. I found the suggestion somewhere and it worked. I didn't have the issue on my local install so I never delved into the how and why it works or what was wrong.